# Unable to get tikzDevice to work

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, tikz

I have a problem with `tikzDevice`. I'm using the latest versions of `R` (with latest knitr and `tikzDevice` packages) and `RStudio`, updated TeX Live to 2015 binaries (and I think I have all the required packages).
When I try to output graphics to `tikzDevice`, compilation hangs. Other graphics devices like `PDF` or `CairoPNG` work without a problem.

As an example, I tried to compile a the simple code below from `RStudio` with `XeLaTeX` (set as the default `LaTeX` compiler in `RStudio`), but it hangs forever after using the TikZ metrics dictionary.
What I see is that the compilation actually produces a file with `.tikz` extension in the "figure" folder, which can be successfully compiled if I run `XeLaTeX` on it.

I attached below the complete log from `RStudio` 'Compile PDF' console output pane while it hangs:

```
Le chargement a n�cessit� le package : knitr

processing file: test.Rnw
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: logi FALSE
 $ cache  : logi FALSE

  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: fig1 (with options) 
List of 3
 $ eval: logi TRUE
 $ echo: logi FALSE
 $ dev : chr "tikz"

Creating new TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    test-tikzDictionary
Using TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    test-tikzDictionary

Le chargement a n�cessit� le package : knitr 

processing file: knitr-graphics.Rnw
  |..                                                               |   2%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...                                                              |   5%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: logi FALSE
 $ cache  : logi FALSE

  |.....                                                            |   7%
   inline R code fragments

  |......                                                           |  10%
label: test-plot (with options) 
List of 1
 $ eval: logi FALSE

  |........                                                         |  12%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........                                                       |  15%
label: pdf-dev (with options) 
List of 4
 $ ref.label: chr "test-plot"
 $ dev      : chr "pdf"
 $ out.width: chr "\\linewidth"
 $ echo     : logi FALSE

  |...........                                                      |  17%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.............                                                    |  20%
label: png-dev (with options) 
List of 4
 $ ref.label: chr "test-plot"
 $ dev      : chr "png"
 $ out.width: chr "\\linewidth"
 $ echo     : logi FALSE

  |..............                                                   |  22%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................                                                 |  24%
label: cairo-png-dev (with options) 
List of 4
 $ ref.label: chr "test-plot"
 $ dev      : chr "CairoPNG"
 $ out.width: chr ".5\\linewidth"
 $ echo     : logi FALSE

  |.................                                                |  27%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: two-high (with options) 
List of 3
 $ fig.width : num 3
 $ fig.height: num 2.5
 $ out.width : chr ".49\\linewidth"

Using TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    knitr-graphics-tikzDictionary
```

And an exerpt of the `tikzStringWidthCalc.log` found in R temporary folder:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.6.25)  1 JUL 2015 13:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**c:/Users/guyader/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqwmJYG/tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
(c:/Users/guyader/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpqwmJYG/tikzStringWidthCalc.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
```

[...]

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 30.
tikzTeXWidth=4.80003pt
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.37 \@@end

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 23160 strings out of 495610
 491023 string characters out of 6186855
 478788 words of memory out of 5000000
 26156 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6670 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,54p,10417b,529s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
```

In addition, if I run the command `knit("test.Rnw")` from R console, I get this:

```
processing file: test.Rnw
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: logi FALSE
 $ cache  : logi FALSE

  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: fig1 (with options) 
List of 3
 $ eval: logi TRUE
 $ echo: logi FALSE
 $ dev : chr "tikz"

Using TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    test-tikzDictionary
Quitting from lines 14-17 (test.Rnw) 
Error: failed to compile figure/graphics-fig1-1.tikz to PDF
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32\xelatex.exe" "graphics-fig1-1.tikz"' had status 1
```

Though, again if run `xelatex` on the `.tikz` graphics file from a windows command prompt, it successfully compiles to PDF.

Here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1
```

Following up on my problem with `tikzDevice`, the only workaround I found is to output the graphics to another device like png, add `usepackage{tikz}` to the preamble, call `tikz()` inside the code chunk and `\input{}` the resulting `.tex` figure like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(tikzDevice)
options(formatR.arrow=TRUE,width=50,tikzDefaultEngine='xetex')
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figure/graphics-', cache.path='cache/graphics-', fig.align='center', dev='png', fig.width=5,     fig.height=5, fig.show='hold', cache=TRUE, par=TRUE, concordance=TRUE)
@

\begin{figure} 

<<fig1,eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>= 
library(ggplot2)
setwd("~/")
td <- getwd()
tf <- file.path(td,'fig1.tex')
tikz(tf, standAlone=F, bareBones=F)
qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg, colour = factor(cyl))
dev.off()
@

\input{fig1.tex}

\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

This way I can get the consistency of fonts from using tikz, but it would be much easier to have `tikzDevice()` to work.