# knitr compilation hangs when using tikz device

Tags: r, knitr, tikz

I'm currently making my first attempt at reproducible research using Rstudio (0.99.486), R (3.2.2), Tex Live 2015, knitr (1.11) and tikzDevice (0.8.1), on Windows 7.

To cut a long story short, when I used dev='pdf' I have no problems compiling, however, as soon as I set any chunk to use dev='tikz', the compilation hangs (I've left the MWE below for over an hour).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=F, cache=F>>=
library(knitr)
@

Here is some text.
Next is a pdf plot:

<<test1, dev='pdf'>>=
plot(c(1,2),c(2,3))
@

Next is the same but using tikz:

<<test2, dev='tikz'>>=
plot(c(1,2),c(2,3))
@

\end{document}
```

If I change the last chunk to use dev='pdf' instead of tikz, it will compile fine. If it's set as tikz, I get the following - but it never finishes.

```
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: MWE.Rnw
  |.........                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...................                                              |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 2
 $ include: symbol F
 $ cache  : symbol F

  |............................                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.....................................                            |  57%
label: test1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ dev: chr "pdf"

  |..............................................                   |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................................         |  86%
label: test2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ dev: chr "tikz"

Using TikZ metrics dictionary at:
    MWE-tikzDictionary
```

If I just do a plot in R manually using tikz(), it works just fine, so I'm assuming the problem is to do with knitr + tikzDevice. I'm at a bit of a loss and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Strange, if I put \usepackage{tikz} in the preamble, it now gets past the stage above, but still fails. Even if I then comment out the \usepackage{tikz} line! I assume it must have generated the dictionary suitably the first time and doesn't need to update it. Anyway, I now get loads of messages, the last section being:

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Quitting from lines 21-22 (MWE.Rnw) 
Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) : 
TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
or character:

    m

Common reasons for failure include:
  * The string contains a character which is special to LaTeX unless
escaped properly, such as % or $.
  * The string makes use of LaTeX commands provided by a package and
the tikzDevice was not told to load the package.

The contents of the LaTeX log of the aborted run have been printed above,
it may contain additional details as to why the metric calculation failed.
Calls: knit ... print.recordedplot -> replayPlot -> <Anonymous> -> getMetricsFromLatex

Execution halted
```

I didn't originally put that package call in the preamble in because the Graphics Demo on the knitr homepage doesn't have it; and, reading the rest of the messages, knitr appears to load it automatically anyway. No idea why that changed things then.

I think it is probably a similar problem as this: [Unable to get tikzDevice to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163917/unable-to-get-tikzdevice-to-work)

Oh, and using the recommended fix for similar sounding problems:

```
devtools::install_github( 'yihui/tikzDevice' )
```

doesn't seem to work either. Now it hangs here (whether \usepackage{tikz} is in the preamble or not):

```
label: test2 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ dev: chr "tikz"
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: Did you really add `\usepackage[tikz}` to your preamble or is it `\usepackage{tikz}`?

Comment: Oooops typo in my question, but not in the actual code. It would throw up all sorts of obvious errors with that typo! I will correct the question now, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a LaTeX log file at `figure/test2-1.log`? If you do, are there any error messages in the log?

Comment: If I compile with no tikz package load in the preamble - so it just hangs - then I get nothing test2 related there. If I do load tikz in the preamble then I don't get a .log file, BUT, it does seem to generate a perfectly serviceable test2-1.tikz file. The same happens if I apply the tikzDevice update. I've tried deleting the tikzDictionary in the main folder each time before running. I can't seem to get the in-between error to happen again now. I think this is likely to be a Windows quirk - I will try on OS X when I get home.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a Windows thing. Tried both OS X and Linux at home.

Comment: I am compiling a beamer presentation with lots of tikz plots. I never had a problem the last few weeks but now I get the same error (no metrics for character 'm') and not a single plot is created. How can that happen? I did not change a thing...